# Setting up an existing Eclipse IDE with JDK 1.6

Tags: eclipse, java

My PC : Win 7 32-bit , Eclipse Kepler

Initially, I had JDK 1.7 . Then ,due to my project , I have to now run jdk 1.6 , which I just installed. File name :"jdk-6u25-windows-i586.exe" .I ran it and installed it in my G:// drive . Now  , how do I get my Eclipse IDE to run that version (1.6) of jdk ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To setup the compiler

```
Right click on your Project->Properties->Java Compiler->Select 1.6
```

To set the jre:

```
Menu->Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs- > Add JDK6/jre and remove others.
```

Comment: Thanks ,for a double check,my checkbox ,Use compliance from execution environment, was unchecked .I unchecked it and then set Compiler Compliance Level to 1.6 .Is it right ?

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yeah thats correct!

Comment: So , do In have to set the jre also ??

Comment: @GaurangTandon Yeah if you want both your compilation and execution environment to be jave version 6

Comment: So ,what I get after `>Preferences->Java->Installed JREs- >  ` is http://i41.tinypic.com/10zstxs_th.jpg

Comment: @GaurangTandon select the default standard jre and rest of the steps are self explanatory.

Comment: Not letting me press next : http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=w1saxf&s=5

Comment: @GaurangTandon You have to enter the details such as jre home and directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
Window -> Preferences-> Java-> Installed Jres -> Add 1.6 -> select
```

Will set-up the global default JRE for your IDE.

If you want to set it up on per project bases you should use:

```
Project Properties -> Preferences-> Java-> Installed Jres -> Add 1.6 -> select
```